# When I unplug USB, "aborted journal detected"

Tags: debian, filesystems

When I unplug a USB flash drive, my Debian system crashes, I get "Input/output error", because my system detects "aborted journal" and mounts root filesystem in read only.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you eject it?? `sudo eject /dev/sda` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35508/eject-usb-drives-eject-command Just unmounting will not necessarily finalize any writes.

Comment: I didn't know about the `eject` command, previously I just `umount`ed it.